At step 92 for typewriter 21327 don’t see a way to connect the last two pieces to the spacebar
It looks like one of the legs of 6005331 (Technic, Axle and Pin Connector Hub with 2 Perpendicular Axles: ) should connect to the rubber piece 4198367 (Technic, Axle Connector Double - Flexible Rubber: ) but neither leg is long enough. Nothing else to attach 6005331 as far as I can tell. How does it attach?

By adding a picture it might be easier for someone to see if anything is wrong with your assembly.

Step 92 does not involve any rubber pieces:

The two technic 90° connectors go through the 2x6 plates and each attaches to the underside of a 2x2 round plate that you added on steps 85-87:

Note that the 2x2 plates do have an axle hole at its center (that should fit the 90° connector).
